# Java Configuration in VS Code - Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, java-18

I really need your help: I can't install and configure Java in VS Code, on Linux Mint.

I've looked for videos, tutorials and the like, but without success. I've already edited `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `/etc/enviroment` and finally, my last configuration attempt was `/etc/profile`, where I included:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-18-openjdk-amd64/
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
export JAVA_HOME PATH CLASSPATH
```

However, when I try to run a Run and Debug in VS Code, the return I get is just this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeGQN.png)

This way, I can't run something in Java in VS Code.

Comment: How did you install Java?  Are you using the package manager?  Have you verified what is actually in `/usr/lib/jvm`?  Java 18 has not been supported in over a year but the concepts should still work with supported versions such as 17 and 21.

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

The error prompts that the jdk path you set is wrong. Please set it to the root directory of the java installation path. (*At least **JDK 17** version is required*).

> Specifies the folder path to the JDK (**17 or more recent**) used to launch the Java Language Server. This setting will replace the Java extension's embedded JRE to start the Java Language Server.
>
> On Windows, backslashes must be escaped, i.e.
>
> "java.jdt.ls.java.home":"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0_3"

Also you are using *Code Runner* to execute the program, which may throw an error. Please use the official Java extension package to execute the program.

[image]